# External CSS is not Working but Internal CSS

Tags: html, css

I am a fresher in HTML and CSS, I am trying to link my CSS file externally to my HTML file but is not able to do so, but Internal CSS is working. Please help in fixing this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Colleen</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/firststyle.css"></link>
    <style type="text/css">
        @font-face
        {
            font-family: avengers;
            src: url('avengersital.ttf'); 
        }       
        .heading
        {
            color: red;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: avengers;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <h1 class="heading">AVENGERS</h1>
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">one</a>
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">two</a>
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">three</a>
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">four</a>
</header>
<section>
    <h2 id = "hola">Favorite Foods</h2>
    <ul class = "list">
        <li>Apples</li>
        <li>Pizza</li>
        <li>Crab</li>
        <li>Choclate cake</li>
    </ul>
</section>
<section>
    <h2 id = "holareturns">Achievements</h2>
    <label for="file" id = "filelabel">Progress in this course(100%)</label>
    <progress id="file" value="100" max="100"></progress>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="filea" id = "filealabel">Progress in the specialization capstone(20%)</label>
    <progress id="filea" value="20" max="100"></progress>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="fileb" id = "fileblabel">Progress in life goals(67%)</label>
    <progress id="fileb" value="67" max="100"></progress>
</section>
<section>
    <h2 class="nothing"> More About Me</h2>
    <details>
        <summary>My Childhood</summary>
        <p> I grew up in Ashtabula Ohio. I lived near Lake Erie and I really miss the sunsets over water
        </p>
    </details>
</section>
<footer>
<img src= "http://www.intro-webdesign.com/images/newlogo.png" alt = "wd4e Logo">
    <caption>This page was created by Vaibhav Sharma & Colleen van Lent, To learn more about web design, visit <a href="http://www.intro-webdesign.com">Intro To Web Design</a></caption>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

and my CSS is

```
 @font-face{
    font-family: avengers !important;
    src: url('avengersital.ttf') !important; 
}
heading{
    color: red !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    font-family: avengers !important;
}
```

I have tried using !important in all lines of CSS and tried using without it, I have used full folder location in href in HTML but still doesn't work.

Edited: So my code has worked as I was using '\' in the location where I had to use'/' for connecting my CSS with my HTML. I am attending the change

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Colleen</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="A:/css/style.css"></link>
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <h1 class="heading">AVENGERS</h1>
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">one</a>
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">two</a>
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">three</a>
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">four</a>
</header>
<section>
    <h2 id = "hola">Favorite Foods</h2>
    <ul class = "list">
        <li>Apples</li>
        <li>Pizza</li>
        <li>Crab</li>
        <li>Choclate cake</li>
    </ul>
</section>
<section>
    <h2 id = "holareturns">Achievements</h2>
    <label for="file" id = "filelabel">Progress in this course(100%)</label>
    <progress id="file" value="100" max="100"></progress>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="filea" id = "filealabel">Progress in the specialization capstone(20%)</label>
    <progress id="filea" value="20" max="100"></progress>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="fileb" id = "fileblabel">Progress in life goals(67%)</label>
    <progress id="fileb" value="67" max="100"></progress>
</section>
<section>
    <h2 class="nothing"> More About Me</h2>
    <details>
        <summary>My Childhood</summary>
        <p> I grew up in Ashtabula Ohio. I lived near Lake Erie and I really miss the sunsets over water
        </p>
    </details>
</section>
<footer>
<img src= "http://www.intro-webdesign.com/images/newlogo.png" alt = "wd4e Logo">
    <caption>This page was created by Vaibhav Sharma & Colleen van Lent, To learn more about web design, visit <a href="http://www.intro-webdesign.com">Intro To Web Design</a></caption>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your answers everyone!!
Peace!

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The `<link>` tag does not have a closing tag.

Comment: Actually it can have a closing tag, it is not compulsory to use it, that's the rule

Comment: No it may not! And [no such thing even exists](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-link-element). And it generates an error in the validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use absolute path as

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\VAIBHAV SHARMA\Desktop\html+css_projects\learning\css\firststyle.css"></link>`

should change to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/firststyle.css"></link>
```

I assumpt that your HTML file and css folder have same level.

May be you miss dot for class `.heading` instead of `heading`

I reproduce in local it worked.

[image]
[image]

Comment: did you refresh page by ctrl + f5 ?

Comment: Yes I refreshed it

Comment: where is class heading in your html?

Comment: See the the <body> and the <header> you will see the class

Comment: Thanks for your answer I was using '\' in location but I had to use '/'

Comment: You copied his HTML with the closing, invalid `</link>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\Users\VAIBHAV SHARMA\Desktop\html+css_projects\learning\css\firststyle.css
```

in the above route of your css file there should be the proper naming of your folder and use `/` instead of `\`

like `C:/Users/VAIBHAV-SHARMA/Desktop/htmlcss_projects/learning/css/firststyle.css`

Answer (score 0):

first of all I don't see any internal CSS applied in your source HTML, so can you update your code with the internal styling ?

Secondly, as per the most important rule of CSS - 
**"Internal CSS will overwrite external CSS, and inline styles will overwrite internal and external CSS"**
https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-best-practice-inline-internal-or-external-CSS

In case of your current code - where you're pointing to an external CSS - there could be a probability that your HTML's reference is incorrect, are the HTML and CSS files not in same folder ? try referring using relative URL - like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/firststyle.css"></link>
```

Finally - I think your CSS should be header (not heading)

```
header{
    color: red !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    font-family: avengers !important;
}
```

Comment: updated the code. They are in same folder and using header also doesn't give any result

Comment: Thanks my problem just got solved. I was using '\' in the location where I had to use'/' for connecting my CSS with my HTML.

Answer (score 0):

HTML External Resource Link element (`link`) will be used like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/examples/link-element-example.css" />
```

You have to use forward slash (`/`) not backslash (`\`).

[Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) about `link` tag.

Comment: So my code has worked as I was using '\' in the location where I had to use'/' for connecting my CSS with my HTML.
Thanks for your response, you can see above the edited version